# Animating (or setting to fully transparent) StatusBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I've encountered a problem with transitioning between screens in Jetpack Compose. By default when we navigate in Compose it applies CrossFade animation. The problem is that my second screen has totally different color, so i want StatusBar and optionally NavigationBar to be animated the same way the screen does, but I don't know how.

[The gif showing the prolem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OVL7.gif)

I've tried to make StatusBar Transparent by doing `systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(Color.Transparent)`, but the StatusBar just became white, so it didn't work.

Any propositions are welcome :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Edge to Edge configuration? In general It should fix your problem, as It will use your screen colors.

Comment: The screen consists of Scaffold and a Column inside. If you mean Modifier.fillMaxSize(), it doesn't work on neither Scaffold nor the content. If you mean something else, please provide the code ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).